# How to select text in a TextBox with the caret positioned at the START of the selection?

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm using a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`. It is possible to select text by using the keyboard in such a way that the caret is positioned at the *start* of the selection - by holding Shift and moving the caret to the left.

I would like to do the same programmatically.

For example, suppose I have a text box with the text "Some sample text". I would like the "sample" word to be selected, and the caret to be positioned just before the "s" in "sample".

If I do this:

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 5;
textbox.SelectionLength = 6;
```

then I get the word selected, but the caret is just after "e" in "sample".

If I do this:

```
textbox.SelectionStart = 11;
textbox.SelectionLength = -6;
```

I get an exception.

How can I position the caret at the start of the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't that is possible to program. As it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761661(VS.85).aspx) native windows controls displays a flashing caret at the end position regardless of the relative values of start and end.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the link, it really does seem to be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Very few things are impossible...

```
textbox.select(11, 0);
SendKeys.Send("+{LEFT}+{LEFT}+{LEFT}+{LEFT}+{LEFT}+{LEFT}");
```

Comment: problem with that is if you have any keyboard processing logic around the text box, it gets called for each of those simulated keys.