# Select text in a TextBox with the cursor being on the first character

Tags: c#, winforms, textselection, cursor-position

I want to select the whole text in a TextBox **without** jumping to the end.

I tried different settings and came to the following - more general - observation:

If you select text within a TextBox with your mouse you can do this from right to left. The cursor is positioned on the left-most character. But it seems that there's no way to set this reverse selection by code. **How could one reach this programmatically?**

The **main goal** is still, that after clicking the "SelectAll" button the beginning of the text should be visible (This **is** possible by selecting the whole text reversly by mouse...).

This mini-programm makes it easy to test around.

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    Button btnSelectAll = new Button();
    Button btnSelectPart = new Button();

    public Form1() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Size = new Size(300, 300);

        txt.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        txt.Size = new Size(150, 35);
        txt.Text = "This is a quite long text, to long to be shown in this TextBox!";
        this.Controls.Add(txt);

        btnSelectPart.Location = new Point(10, 50);
        btnSelectPart.Size = new Size(50, 35);
        btnSelectPart.Text = "part";
        btnSelectPart.Click += btnSelectPart_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(btnSelectPart);

        btnSelectAll.Location = new Point(60, 50);
        btnSelectAll.Size = new Size(50, 35);
        btnSelectAll.Text = "all";
        btnSelectAll.Click += btnSelectAll_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(btnSelectAll);
    }

    void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        this.txt.Focus();
        this.txt.SelectAll();
    }

    void btnSelectPart_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        this.txt.Focus();
        this.txt.Select(8, 3);
    }
}
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184448/5089204), which is a duplicate indeed, but it is 6 years old... Hope there is something possible today...

Comment: `You can control cursor position (and selection) with txtbox.SelectionStart and txtbox.SelectionLength properties.`

Comment: @MethodMan, did you really read my question? You can believe me, that I've tried all the obvious things. Look, there is a question (*useful*) explaining the goal (**cursor at the beginning of a selection** *clear*) and a specially written example for the SO community to test this (*effort*) and a link to a possible duplicate I've found (*research*).  If you are the down voter you might think about this...

Comment: There hasn't been any new development in the Winforms API since before WPF came along, and Winforms uses the native Windows Edit control, which hasn't been changed in even longer. A six-year-old answer to this question is still a spring chicken compared to the age of the actual API.

Comment: Hey, I've found that duplicate myself, but this is six years old! And there's no answer, just a *sorry not possible*... Is it illegit to trust in the great SO community that someone has found at least a hack (besides `SendKeys`)?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, This question is closed as a duplicate now. The first voter is one who did not even read it, the second says: *There's a six years old duplicate! You should not even ask!* There's something wrong with SO: If someone asks *What is virtual other than new? I've found many answers, but I do not understand it*, there will be 30 comments, 5 answers within 3 minutes (and further 10 later) and tons of votes. This is an elaborate question, down voted (by a non-reader) and closed due to a six years old duplicate...  :-(

Comment: Your question was a duplicate from the outset. Even if there was a new solution today, that doesn't change the duplicate nature of the question; age of the question is irrelevant. In this case, the answer hasn't even changed, so the marked duplicate tells you everything you need to know. If what you ask is impossible, then answering "you can't do that" is a perfectly valid answer, and that's the answer you can find in the duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, if you cannot solve a problem and you find such an old duplicate **without** a solution, you would never ever ask a new question? You are sure, that within six years nobody has found a way to solve this? Yes, I've found that duplicate and I placed it in my question (look at the last line, no edits up to now!). In my eyes this is a legit question. Just place a comment, and state your opinion, but why closing this...? SO is sometimes a place for script kiddies and peacocky profs... (Don't want to offend you personally, you are an expert as I can see in your profile...)

Comment: I'm closing it, because that's what we do on Stack Overflow with questions that are duplicates of existing questions. Note that your question has not been deleted (as of yet). It may well remain as a useful guidepost to others to find the original question. But it's the same question as the old one, and thus by definition is a duplicate. I'm sure short of implementing your own control from scratch or using one of the `SendKeys` workarounds, there is no new solution to this since six years ago. The implementation of the API hasn't changed since then, so why would the answer?

Comment: For the record: I personally spent at least half an hour trying different things with the low-level unmanaged API (because I'm _sure_ you can't do this through the managed code API in `System.Windows.Forms`) and verified myself that any of the potential work-arounds in the native control are not useful. The documentation clearly enumerates all of the possible scrolling commands for the control, and I tried all of them.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for your efforts. I appreciate this very much!